# JQuery Infinite Scrolling with Isotope prefill not working in IE8

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I am using [JQuery Infinite Scrolling](https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll) and [JQuery Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) with the prefill option. It works fine in all major browsers except for IE8. In IE8 only the first bunch of elements is loaded and nothing more.

What do I have to do, to get prefill working in IE8?

Here is my JavaScript:

```
var $container = $('#container');

$container.imagesLoaded(function(){
    $container.isotope({
        itemSelector : '.item',
        animationEngine: 'best-available',
        masonry: {
            columnWidth: 150
        }
    });
});


$container.infinitescroll({
    prefill: true,
    animate : false,
    bufferPx : 40, 
    binder: $(window), 
    navSelector  : '#page-nav',    // selector for the paged navigation 
    nextSelector : '#next-page',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
    itemSelector : '.item',     // selector for all items you'll retrieve
    loading: {
        finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.',
        msgText: "<em>Loading ...</em>",
        img: 'http://i.imgur.com/qkKy8.gif'
        }
    },
    // call Isotope as a callback
    function(newElements, data, url) {


        // hide new items while they are loading
        var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
        // ensure that images load before adding to Isotope layout
        $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
            // show elems now they're ready
            $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
            $container.isotope( 'appended', $( newElements ) );

        });

    }
);
```

My Css:

```
.item {
  margin: 5px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using a compatible version of jQuery for IE8? (Remember, version 2.0.0 does not support IE8 or below)

Comment: I am using Jquery 1.8.3